# Is there any way to reduce time complexity of the function given below?

Tags: c

This is the function to calculate the factorial of very large numbers. This works perfectly fine but the time complexity is quite high. How to reduce time complexity?

This function is called once.
Current time to find factorial 0f 1 million is 40 000ms;
Expected time: 10 000ms

```
static void calcfactorial(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int carry, i, j;
    len = factorial[0] = 1;
    for (i = 1; i < LEN; i++)
        factorial[i] = 0;
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        carry = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < len; j++)
        {
            factorial[j] = factorial[j] * i + carry;
            carry = factorial[j] / 10;
            factorial[j] = factorial[j] % 10;
        }
        while (carry)
        {
            factorial[len++] = carry % 10;
            carry = carry / 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're doing work with large numbers you should probably use a library like GMP.

Comment: The code does not contain a definition of `factorial`. Edit the question to provide complete code. Why are you using a base of 10? Why not 100, 1000, 10000, or more? Do you need powers of ten or can you use 65536? Is this function used just once or called multiple times? If it is called multiple times, remember each factorial it computes so it does not have to be recomputed later. (This is called memoization.) How long is it taking? How short do you need it to be?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Changing the base won't change the complexity, that's just a constant factor.

Comment: Do not always iterate `j` to `len`. Only go to the last non-zero element in `factorial` so far.

Comment: @Barmar: They likely want an absolute reduction for some online judge or class assignment grader, not really a complexity reduction. Learn to recognize the signs. Novice students use base ten. More advanced students who understand complexity have advanced beyond that and would not iterate unnecessarily to `len`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Maybe, but I think coding competitions often require you to come up with a clever algorithm that avoids exponential complexity, and reducing the coefficient isn't usually enough.

Comment: I've never been in a coding competition, they weren't a thing when I learned to program (I was a Mathlete in high school, though), so I can't be sure. I'm just going by what I've seen on this site.

Comment: Using base 10 also has the advantage that no extra logic is needed to convert the base for printing the result in decimal.

Comment: @dbush: That is a disadvantage here, as it conflicts with the goal of reducing time. Doing the calculations in base 10 or a power of it requires divisions, which are commonly time consuming. Doing the calculations in a power of two base would be faster and worth the effort of converting the final result to decimal.

Comment: 40 seconds is pretty good. Using a base 10**13 implementation, it takes 270 seconds on a 2.9 GHz Intel Core i7 on a MacBookPro13,3. Still, you are likely to get the four-fold speedup you want by using a base larger than 10 and tracking where the non-zero elements in the product array start and end. I believe there are other ways to calculate the factorial that are faster than direct multiplication, but these simple changes should suffice for your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need a four-fold improvement in time, the following may suffice:

- Use a wider (unsigned) integer type, such as `uint64_t`.
- Instead of calculating in base ten, use the largest power of ten, *B*, such that *B*•*N* fits in the integer type<sup>1</sup>, where *N* is the number you are computing the factorial of. For example, for 64-bit integers and 1,000,000!, you could use base 10<sup>13</sup>.
- When doing multiplications, do not multiply by every digit in the product array, as the loop `for (j = 0; j < len; j++)` does. All digits beyond the first start as zero, and they slowly become non-zero as work progresses. Track the highest non-zero digit, and do multiplications only up to that digit, until the product carries into the next digit.
- Similarly, the low digits become zero as the work progresses, due to accumulating factors of the base in the factorial. Track the lowest non-zero digit, and start work there.

A program demonstrating these is below.

A significant cost in this program is the divisions by the base. If you switch to a power-of-two base, these become bitwise operations (shifts for division and bitwise AND operations for remainders), which are much cheaper. This should speed up computing the factorial considerably. However, the final product will have to be converted to decimal for output. That will have a lower cost than computing entirely in decimal, so it is a win.

After that, you might consider [this answer in Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/14476). It suggests restructuring the factorial as powers of primes and using repeated squaring to compute the powers of primes, which are then multiplied.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1343459) suggests using *n*! ≈ sqrt(2π*n*)•(*n*/*e*)<sup>*n*</sup>, which would require more sophisticated mathematics and programming.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> The purpose of using a power of ten is then the result can be directly printed from its base-*B* digits.

### Demonstration

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/*  Define T to be an unsigned integer type.  The larger the better up to the
    widest type supported efficiently (generally the widest type for which the
    processor has arithmetic instructions).

    Define PRIuT to be a printf conversion specifier to print a type T as an
    unsigned decimal numeral.
*/
typedef uint64_t T;
#define PRIuT   PRIu64  


//  Return the base-10 logarithm of x, rounded down.
static unsigned ilog10(T x)
{
    unsigned log = 0;
    for (; 10 <= x; x /= 10)
        ++log;
    return log;
}


//  Return 10**x.
static T iexp10(unsigned x)
{
    T power = 1;
    for (; 0 < x; --x)
        power *= 10;
    return power;
}


int main(void)
{
    //  Set the value we want the factorial of.
    static const T N = 1000000;

    //  Set the maximum value of T by using wrapping.
    static const T MaximumT = -1;

    /*  Determine the maximum number of decimal digits we can use easily:

            Given a number with Digits decimal digits, Digits*N will be
            representable in a T.
    */
    unsigned Digits = ilog10(MaximumT/N);

    /*  Set Base to 10**Digits.  This is the numerical base we will do
        arithmetic in -- like base ten, but more efficient if it is bigger.
    */
    T Base = iexp10(Digits);

    /*  Set an array size that is sufficient to contain N!

        For 1 < N, N! < N**N, so the number of digits in N! is less than
        log10(N**N) = N * log(10).  Since we are using ilog10, which rounds
        down, we add 1 to it to round up, ensuring we have enough room.

        Then we divide that number of digits by the number of digits we will
        have in each array element (and round up, by subtracting one before the
        division and adding one after), and that is the number of array
        elements we allocate.
    */
    size_t S = (N * (ilog10(N)+1) - 1) / Digits + 1;
    T *Product = malloc(S * sizeof *Product);
    if (!Product)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "Error, unable to allocate %zu bytes.\n", S * sizeof *Product);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*  Initialize the array to 1.  L and H remember the index of the lowest
        and highest non-zero array element, respectively.  Since all the
        elements before L or after H are zero, we do not need to use them in
        the multiplication.
    */
    Product[0] = 1;
    size_t L = 0, H = 0;

    //  Multiply the product by the numbers from 2 to N.
    for (T i = 2; i <= N; ++i)
    {
        //  Start with no carry.
        T carry = 0;

        /*  Multiply each significant base-Base digit by i, add the carry in,
            and separate the carry out.  We start separately with the lowest
            non-zero element so we can track if it becomes zero.
        */
        while (1)
        {
            T t = Product[L] * i + carry;
            carry = t / Base;
            if ((Product[L] = t % Base))    //  Leave when digit is non-zero.
                break;
            ++L;    //  If digit is zero, increase L.
        }
        for (size_t j = L+1; j <= H; ++j)
        {
            T t = Product[j] * i + carry;
            carry = t / Base;
            Product[j] = t % Base;
        }

        //  If there is a final carry out, put it in a new significant digit.
        if (0 != carry)
            Product[++H] = carry;
    }

    /*  Print the result.  The first base-Base digit is printed with no
        leading zeros.  All subsequent base-Base digits are printed with
        leading zeros as needed to ensure exactly Digit decimal digits are
        printed.
    */
    printf("%" PRIuT, Product[H]);
    for (size_t j = H; 0 < j--;)
        printf("%0*" PRIuT, Digits, Product[j]);
    printf("\n");

    free(Product);
}
```